# Akka Flow how to apply filter on a JSON data coming from Kafka Topic

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

JSON data coming from Kafka Topic like

```
{
  "Action": "die",
  "Actor": {
    "Attributes": {      
      "exit": "0",
      "node.name": "node-1",
      "name": "6a5426de4d6e"
    },
    "ID": "09a2576ec87e416aaa943f566e54a375d9c325885038195125c4674b104276b6"
  }
}
```

My Akka Flow code snippet is like below

```
def getEvents: Flow[KafkaMessage, ConsumerMessage.CommittableOffset, NotUsed] =
    Flow[KafkaMessage]
      .via(getfromSource) //akka source 
      .wireTap(_.value.map(pprint.log(_))) // I am able to console all the events from kafka topic.
```

I want to apply `filter` (get all exit=0) condition on top of the events getting from the topic by using `.filter` . But unable to make it work . Any guidance or reference will be helpful

Comment: Well, what di you try, what is not working?

Comment: I thought of writing another `.via` function to `filter`. Since pretty new in this not sure what and how to do

Comment: There's a `filter` method on Source/Flows: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/filter.html this should be enough. I'd recommend spending a bit of time looking at possible operations on streams.

Comment: This should be simple like this `.filter(_.Actor.Attributes.exit >0 )` right ? Which is not working.

Comment: Define "not working". How do you see it's not working? `exit` seems to be a `String` in your example

Comment: I tried this `.filter(_.Actor.Attributes.exitCode.toInt >0 )` . I am getting the error `value Actor is not a member of x$1: [Either[Throwable,TopicEvent]].` My `_` is `[Either[Throwable,TopicEvent]]`, I thought `filter` by default takes the `Right`.

Comment: `filter` from the Flow works on an item of the flow which is a `Either` in your case

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, `getfromSource` returns `Either[Throwable,TopicEvent]` so you have to do something like this:

```scala
 Flow[KafkaMessage]
      .via(getfromSource)
      .filter { 
        case Right(event) => event.Actor.Attributes.exitCode.toInt > 0
        case Left(_) => false // or true? Up to you..
      }
```

*Note that the pattern matching can be simplified if you want to.*